# How can I access the id value in this array?

Tags: php, arrays

When I do a `print_r` I get this array:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
      [id] => 5280
   )
)
```

How can I access the id value with PHP?

Comment: It's just a 2 dimensional array. The outer one is numerically indexed, the inner is associative.

Comment: If you had read the [arrays section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of the PHP manual, you wouldn't be asking this question. -1.

Answer (score 7):

You can access it like this

```
$id_value = $your_array[0]['id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$mapped = array_map("current",$array);
echo $mapped[0];
```

This is useful if you have multiple arrays on the root array
eg: `Array(Array(),Array()..)`